# How to break out of a loop

Tags: programming, loops

I have been trying to automate the production of stepped tables that contain conversion factors of all sorts. (See [Protrusion of fractions in tabulars](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12150/protrusion-of-fractions-in-tabulars)).

As part of this I have a rather convoluted macro to convert decimals to fractions. The algorithm works fairly well and sample output is shown below:

[image]

As I am trying to catch common fractions as those found in traditional units (1/12, 3/4, 1/60, 1/3 etc), I would like to be able to break out of the loop once a limit is reached. I have tested it using `FPifgt` or similar but I am getting problems with the double `fi`. Is there a way out of it?

The code is shown below (apologies for length):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,fp}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\count@=1
\def\DecimalToFraction#1{
%helper macro
\FPset\zero{0}
\FPset\X{#1}

%% Set initial values
\FPadd\X{\X}{0.0000000001} % avoid overflows and divisions by zero
\FPset\Zi{\X}
\FPset\Di{1}
\FPset\Dprevious{0}
%% begin loop
\loop\ifnum\count@<13
%% numerator term
\FPtrunc\temp{\Zi}{0} 
\FPsub\temp{\Zi}{\temp}
%% inverse
\FPdiv\Znext{1}{\temp}
%% Find Dnext
\FPtrunc\IntZnext{\Znext}{0}
%% Di x Int{Zi+1}
\FPmul\temp{\Di}{\IntZnext}
\FPadd\temp{\Di}{\Dprevious}
\FPset\Dnext{\temp}
\FPround\Dnext{\Dnext}{0}

%%% Find Ni+1
\FPmul\temp{\X}{\Dnext}
\FPround\temp{\temp}{0}
\FPset\Nnext{\temp}

\FPdiv\ratio{\Nnext}{\Dnext}

\(Z_i=\Znext\to \Nnext/\Dnext =\ratio\)

\FPset{\Dprevious}{\Dnext}
\FPset{\Di}{\Dprevious}
\FPset{\Zi}{\Znext}

\advance\count@ by1
\repeat
%% end of loop

\gdef\NUM{\Nnext}
\gdef\DEN{\Dnext}

\makeatother
}

\def\Test#1{%
\DecimalToFraction{#1}
The number $#1=\frac{\NUM}{\DEN}$

}
\Test{0.375}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do something like this inside TeX? Surely a programming language designed for managing numbers would make more sense for this sort of task...

Comment: @Seamus Handling numbers through TeX is as easy as any language and  you do not need to jump in an out of programs. Problem TeX does not offer a range of datastructures so the problems with if and loops etc.

Comment: @Yiannis: TeX just tends to be a bit slow for that kind of things. :)

Comment: @Yiannis so pick a language with the proper data structures? I'm all for doing stuff in TeX, but it seems like there are easier ways to achieve what you want outside of TeX...

Comment: @Seamus, @Yiannis: I have a few ideas of how to code some standard data structures. Which one(s) would be useful?

Comment: @Bruno If you can come up with some good link lists and sorting it can be very useful. I have some prototypes for objects. I'll dig them out and post a few questions over the next couple of days.

Comment: @Seamus The beauty of combining the calculations - granted is not so easy, when you have recursion etc.. is that you can have "intelligent" documents. At work we do a lot of repetitive reports, calling a few macros resets all the numbers and produces 30 page reports in no time. The example is for a book I am writing so far 80% of all calculations I do as I go along with TeX. It is very similar to literate programming except the code is in the book!

Comment: @Yiannis perhaps luatex or at least latex3 would afford more flexibility, and have the same advantages. Or if the numbercrunching got heavier, Sweave and R would be the obvious choice...

Comment: @Seamus I agree about LaTeX3, but need to give the Team some more time to stabilize expl3's `fp` equivalent. For real number crunching I use R and Python.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To abort the loop after the current iteration simply `\let` the internal `\iterate` macro to `\relax`. 
If you want to skip the rest of the loop code 
you can use a macro defined to `\fi\iffalse` for this (as Bruno already said).

---

Abort at end of current iteration:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcount\mycount

\mycount=1

\loop\ifnum\mycount<13

 % Do calculation
 \typeout{Loop: \the\mycount}

 \ifnum\mycount>5
    \let\iterate\relax
 \fi
 \advance\mycount by 1\relax
\repeat

\end{document}
```

---

Abort immediately:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\breakloop{\fi\iffalse}
\begin{document}

\newcount\mycount

\mycount=1

\loop\ifnum\mycount<13

 % Do calculation
 \typeout{Loop: \the\mycount}

 \ifnum\mycount>5
    \expandafter\breakloop
 \fi

 \typeout{ more }
 \advance\mycount by 1\relax
\repeat

\end{document}
```

### Explanation:

First lets look at the (LaTeX) definitions of `\loop` and `\repeat`:

```
\loop:
\long macro:#1\repeat ->\def \iterate {#1\relax \expandafter \iterate \fi }\iterate \let \iterate \relax . 

\repeat:
\fi.
```

As you see `\loop` stores everything between it and `\repeat` into `\iterate` which calls itself. This recursion implements the loop. The `\expandafter` ensures that no dangling `\fi`s get accumulated. As long the loop `\if...` is true the text is executed, and `\iterate` is called again *after* the `\fi`. If the conditional is false everything until the `\fi` is skipped including the `\expandafter`. However if `\iterate` is changed to `\relax` the recursion stops independent of the conditional. Because this happens after the `\fi` no cleanup is required.

The `\breakloop` generates a `\fi\iffalse`. The `\fi` closes the loop conditional and the `\iffalse` makes TeX skip everything until the final `\fi` like the loop conditional would do.

---

If you need to use FP conditionals inside the loop you have to make them "skip save" first. The problem is that FP define own `if` switches as *macros* which aren't recognized when TeX skips over an *false* path. To fix this define macros like this

```
\def\xFPiflt#1#2{%
  \FPiflt{#1}{#2}%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
```

Then use `\xFPiflt\x\y{<true>}{<false>}` instead of `\FPiflt\x\y <true> \else <false> \fi`.

Comment: @Martin thanks. It works nicely with `\ifnum` but not with the FP conditionals. Any idea? they have the same structure like `ifnum`.

Comment: @Yiannis: Try to move `\breakloop` to the outside of the FP conditional e.g. by only executing `\let\x\breakloop` inside that conditional and later simply execute `\x` (which default to `\empty` or `\relax` otherwise).

Comment: @Yiannis: I didn't know much about `fp` before, but I just saw that they use *macros* to define own `\ifxxx` switches which is incompatible with the skipping process of TeX! Can you give an example of a FP conditional inside a `\loop`? I don't think it will work at all.

Comment: @Yiannis: See my updated answer on how to use FP conditionals inside `\loop` or `\ifnum` etc.

Comment: @Martin I would post a new question tomorrow with a minimal, I think it would be better.

Comment: @Martin thanks, it worked with a small correction: `\xFPiflt{\x\y}{<true>}{<false>}`.

Comment: @Yiannis: I see. My bad. I mistook the syntax of `\FPiflt`. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 5):

The loop has the structure

```
\loop
...
\if...
...
\repeat
```

If you are between `\if` and `\repeat`, you can issue `\fi\iffalse` to close the current `\if` and skip all the text until `\repeat` (or rather, until a `\fi` that is produced by `\loop...\repeat`). This will not work if your loop is `\loop...\if...\else...\repeat`.

A more robust solution is to place `\@gobble\mysentinel` just before `\repeat`, and then use the following macro to go out of the loop:

```
\def\Iwanttobreakfree#1\mysentinel{\iffalse}
```

This will throw away all the tokens until `\mysentinel`, including `\@gobble`, and the `\iffalse` makes sure that the loop stops.

Comment: @bruno thanks, why do you add an argument to the macro `Iwanttobreakfree` ?

Comment: Nice answer (and nice macro name)!

Comment: @Yiannis: `#1` will be all the tokens until `\mysentinel`: those that you want to get rid of (notice that `#1` does not appear in the replacement text of `Iwanttobreakfree`).

Comment: @Yiannis: This is how we do loops for `expl3`, using some slightly different names (`\q_recursion_stop` is the key marker), with the 'gobble' function having the catchy name `\use_none_delimit_by_q_recursion_stop:w` :-)

Comment: @Joseph: I have to admit that I probably got the idea from reading the `expl3` code.

Comment: @Bruno: I was not sure - I was more pointed at the name, as the '`use_none`' sort-of explains about `#1` :-)

Comment: I should add that the `expl3` approach does not use `\iffalse`, but then things are all constructed to allow breaking 'from the ground up'. (We don't use Knuth's `\loop` approach at present.)

Comment: @Joseph I just got too busy lately, but it was my new year's resolution to seriously get into LaTeX3:)

Comment: @Bruno: What of `\let\mysentinel\relax` (outside the loop) with `\def\Iwanttobreakfree#1\mysentinel#2\repeat{\fi}` (inside)? I am a learner!

Comment: @Ahmed: I think that would not work. See Martin Scharrer's answer above; he explains how `\loop` works, leaving no `\repeat` behind. So you'd be better off using `\iterate` rather than `\repeat` as a delimiter. About `\let\mysentinel\relax`: that works, but it is not expandable. Not an issue here, but in a better (expandable) version of loops (see `expl3`), it would be a problem, leaving the `\mysentinel` in every step.