# How to create a random math problem in LaTeX?

Tags: random-numbers

I want to create a math problem-solution sheet. The coefficients `a`, `b`, `c` must be assigned on the fly at random so the generated pdf will show a numeric quadratic equation rather than a symbolic quadratic equation. Note `a` must not be zero.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Problem}
Let \(x_1\) and \(x_2\) be the roots of \(a x^2 +bx +c=0\). Find  \(x_1x_2\).

\section{Solution}
\[
x_1x_2=\frac{c}{a}
\]
\end{document}
```

Please kindly make the solution get automatically simplified. For example: `\frac{c}{a}=3` when `a=2` and `c=6`.

---

Actually the real case is more complex than this one. Not only the equations must be generated at random, but also the associated graphic plots that I write in PSTricks.

---

I chose Paulo's answer because using Maxima as the computation engine is very very great idea. Other answers are also good and creative, especially Altermundus'.

Comment: Pretty interesting question. I remember dealing with something similar, but my approach was quite hybrid. It was something like generating random coefficients in LaTeX, call a computer algebra system to solve it for me, then redirect the output back to LaTeX. I used Maxima's function `tex(solve(equation))` which gives me the result in the LaTeX math format.

Comment: http://andreas.scherbaum.la/blog/archives/668-Generate-random-number-in-LaTeX.html

Comment: Oh no.. I did not see `SageTeX` has been used. :-(

Comment: Yes. That post inspired me to create a lot of tests/quizzes using specific problem types where the numbers are created at random (and then create a solution sheet) using the `sagetex` package. It is the package to learn if you are teaching math

Comment: If this is still going to be open for a bounty, what sort of random problems are you looking for: arithmetic, algebra, precalculus, discrete math? Or you still want quadratic mentioned and already solved?

Comment: @DJP: I want to see how  SageTeX produce a list of `n` multiple choice problems by randomizing a template, for example, about solving  system equations of 2 unknown `x` and `y`,  each equation is either linear or quadratic with rational coefficients. The answer key for each question must show the process, graph, and intersecting point(s) in exact values/labels (not rounded decimal numbers).

Comment: Sage can do all this but programming it with the requirements you want adds many levels of complexity to the programming. Sage also doesn't give the steps to a solution, that has to be worked into the code which is difficult. Finally, if the goal is to produce a test for the classroom then truly random problems will throw out ugly numbers that make the problem beyond what your class can handle. I've found it works best if you have a template of problem types which have been carefully selected. Compiling changes the numbers to "student friendly" numbers, and update the solutions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a partial solution and probably it's not what you want. However, I'm posting it solely for record purposes, in case anyone would need it. =)

I'll use [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/):

> Maxima is a system for the manipulation of symbolic and numerical expressions, including differentiation, integration, Taylor series, Laplace transforms, ordinary differential equations, systems of linear equations, polynomials, and sets, lists, vectors, matrices, and tensors. Maxima yields high precision numeric results by using exact fractions, arbitrary precision integers, and variable precision floating point numbers. Maxima can plot functions and data in two and three dimensions.

First of all, I created a script file named **solve.cmd** in my working directory:

```
@echo off
rem If Maxima is not in your path, you need to set it.
rem Also, I'm making use of the 'head' command, you can
rem obtain the Win32 version easily with MSys.
set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files\Maxima-5.24.0\bin"
maxima --very-quiet -r %1 | head --lines=-1
```

I'm not in my Linux box right now, but a **.sh** file is similar.

Using Jake's code, I added a call to this script:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document} 

\section{Problem}

\pgfmathsetseed{1}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\coeffa{random(2,10)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\coeffb{random(2,10)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\coeffc{random(2,10)}

% call to the 'solve' script providing the coefficients.
% Maxima's 'solve' function will return x1 and x2, and the
% 'tex' function will convert the answer to TeX. The last
% line of the output will be removed (the 'head' command)
% because Maxima adds a 'false' line to the end of the file.
% Then we redirect the output to a file.
\immediate\write18{solve.cmd "tex(solve(\coeffa*x^2 + (\coeffb*x) + (\coeffc)));" > solution1.tex}

Let \(x_1\) and \(x_2\) be the roots of \(\coeffa x^2 +\coeffb x +\coeffc=0\). Find  \(x_1x_2\).

\section{Solution}

% read the solution
\input solution1

\end{document}
```

I tried to use Maxima's `plot2d` function together with the call, but I failed to fix a minor error with file extensions. I intended to create a `png` plot with `gnuplot` and include it. Sorry, it didn't work yet.

Don't forget to use the `--shell-escape` or `--enable-write18` flag.

**EDIT:** It gave me a tremendous headache, but I guess I found a nice improvement. =)

> I'm not used to Maxima, though I like to use it for simple calculations. If my code is somehow incorrect, please help me improve it. Thanks.

I edited the **solve.cmd** file in my working directory to look like this:

```
@echo off
rem If Maxima is not in your path, you need to set it.
rem Now, I don't use 'head' anymore, but 'grep'. The idea
rem behind this code is:
rem   1. generate the three coefficients,
rem   2. output both equation and solution to a file,
rem   3. get rid of the 'false' lines in the text (Maxima's fault)
rem      (we do this thanks to 'grep' using an inverse flag)
rem   4. direct output to a file 'problem.txt'.
@echo off
set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files\Maxima-5.24.0\bin"
maxima --very-quiet -r "s: make_random_state(true)$ set_random_state(s)$ fullrand(low, high) := floor(random(1.0) * ( 1 + high - low)) + low$ a : fullrand(-10,10)$ s: b : fullrand(-10,10)$ c : fullrand(-10,10)$ tex(a*x^2 + b*x + c); tex(solve(a*x^2 + b*x + c));" | grep -v false > problem.txt
```

Now the tricky part, the LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\immediate\write18{solve.cmd}

\newread\myread
\openin\myread=problem.txt
\read\myread to \theequation
\read\myread to \thesolution

\begin{document}

\section{Problem}

This is our equation:

\theequation

\section{Solution}

And this is our solution:

\thesolution

\end{document}
```

Let's check the code: first of all, we run `solve.cmd`, which outputs both equation and solution to a file named `problem.txt`. Then we create a `\newread\myread` and open this file `\openin\myread=problem.txt`. Now we map the first line to `\theequation` (which is the equation which we defined in our Maxima code) and the second line to `\thesolution` (same logic). Then we call it when needed.

Again, probably some of my Maxima code is faulty. But I hope you get the idea behind this. In case of changing the equation or solution to a inline version, we may probably do some `sed` in it and replace the pattern. =)

Comment: @xport: glad you like it. I'm trying to improve the code as you suggested, but unfortunately I'm not that used with Maxima. __EDIT:__ I hope to come up with something. ;-)

Comment: @xport: hm did you use the `--shell-escape` flag? Unfortunately, a single mistake (like a missing `;`) will break the call. I suffered a lot before getting it right.

Comment: @xport: hm good, at least it worked! The missing `head` command is part of a Win32 port of some useful Unix tools. I uploaded [mine](http://www.mediafire.com/?shf9czs2xiak7e3) for you to use, put in your working directory. I hope it helps. PS: I'm on a fight with Maxima right now. =)

Comment: @xport: Mine came from [MSys/MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/), but I believe it's a big payload unless you want to use `gcc` and related tools. [This project](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) may sound more interesting.

Comment: @xport: hm your code works for me, using MikTeX 2.9. I'm gonna try in another machine with TeXLive.

Comment: @xport: I updated the code. Hope it helps! ;-)

Comment: @xport: the `@echo off`, `rem` and `set` are DOS commands. Basically the `.cmd` file it's the good ol' batch file (`.bat`). The text surrounded by `"` in the `maxima` line is the Maxima language itself.

Comment: @Paulo: Which approach is faster and more fluid coding workflow? Putting all Maxima codes in the `.tex`  file or putting them in `.cmd` file?

Comment: @Paulo: Do you know Razor view engine from Microsoft ASP.NET? It allows us to mix logic codes and HTML markups in  a single HTML file. I have a dream to get the same feature by combining LaTeX markups and Maxima logic codes. :-)

Comment: @xport: in this case, I think the `.cmd` approach is better, since you don't need to pass parameters from the `.tex` file, like our first attempt. But it's up to you. =) Hm, I didn't know about Razor, it seems pretty cool, easy markup. You gave me an idea, I'll plan a `maxima-latex` package and try to provide similar features.

Comment: @Paulo: how to remove the temporary files such as `solution1` in the first attempt?

Comment: @xport: I'm afraid there is no macro for removing an existing file. I guess we can call a specific OS command to remove the file, like `del` or `rm`, but I could not make it work.

Comment: @Paulo: Sometimes the output of solve occupies more than one row. So you will lose the remaining rows.

Comment: @xport: hm I ran the code a few times and could not reproduce this behaviour. One issue I know is that the random number function I wrote (`fullrand`) also allows `a`, `b` and `c` to be zero, then when one of these coefficients is zero, Maxima suppress the output of that term. In some cases, I didn't got a quadratic equation. But it's solely Maxima's fault (well, TBH is my fault). ;-)

Comment: @Paulo: See the issue here http://stackoverflow.com/q/6315732/397524

Answer (score 28):

I know I'm late to the party here, but I would use [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org) and SageTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\section{Problem}

\begin{sagesilent}
a = ZZ.random_element(-10,10)
while a == 0:
   a = ZZ.random_element(-10,10)
b = ZZ.random_element(-10,10)
c = ZZ.random_element(-10,10)
poly = a*x^2 + b*x + c
\end{sagesilent}

Let \(x_1\) and \(x_2\) be the roots of \(\sage{poly}=0\). 
Find  \(x_1x_2\).

\section{Solution}
\[
x_1x_2=\sage{c/a}.
\]

\sageplot{plot(poly) }

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image: output from sagetex]

Comment: A little late but worth the wait! Your solution inspired me to solve the problems I had earlier (with the system finding sagetex.sty) and after spending a couple of hours messing around, it seems clear to me that sagetex package is the "must have" package for those who might use a program like Sage.

Comment: I am using MikTeX on a PC. SageTeX is installed but the output is missing all elements that are to come from Sage. However no error message is produced, any ideas? Also,  I am interested in this because I want to make cheat-proof exams! So I like the output file to be n copies of a set of questions, (n=number of students)  each copy starting on a new page utilizing a new random set of numbers.

Answer (score 15):

The [lcg](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lcg) package contains macros to generate (pseudo) random numbers. A little example (the plot is also generated but using `TikZ`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[counter=coefa,first=-8, last=12]{lcg}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\rand\arabic{coefa}
\let\Coefa\thecoefa

\chgrand[counter=coefb]
\rand\arabic{coefb}
\let\Coefb\thecoefb

\chgrand[counter=coefc]
\rand\arabic{coefc}
\let\Coefc\thecoefc

\section{Problem}
Let \(x_1\) and \(x_2\) be the roots of \( \Coefa x^2 +\Coefb x + \Coefc =0\). Find  \(x_1x_2\).

\section{Solution}
\[
x_1x_2=\frac{\Coefc}{\Coefa}
\]


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel=$x$,
  ylabel={$f(x) = \Coefa x^2 + \Coefb x + \Coefc $}
]
\addplot[color=orange,thick] {\Coefa*x^2 + \Coefb* x + \Coefc};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, when compiling my example you'll get different values for the corfficients, so a different equation and plot will be obtained.

Comment: @xport: I'll think about the simplification problem. I've updated my answer adding the plot of the quadratic function (but using `TikZ`).

Comment: Beautiful answer.

Comment: When I run this I get the same coefficients unless I save the file again and then run it. Then a new set of coefficients show up. I am interested in this because I want to make cheat-proof exams! So I like the output file to be n copies of a set of questions, (n=number of students)  each copy starting on a new page utilizing a new random set of numbers.

Answer (score 9):

To simplify the fractions, you can use [Euclid's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor), using the minimal below with

```
\reduceFrac{27}{81}
$\frac{\rfNumer}{\rfDenom}$
```

will give you 1/3. To simplify to a round number is more difficult, as you need to check if there is a remainder left over, so you will need a decimal to fraction conversion routine. See [How to break out of a loop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12481/how-to-break-out-of-a-loop) at the end of the code, you will find how to use the macros to convert for example 0.375 to the fractional approximation 768/2048. No guarantees for its accuracy, needs a bit of refinement.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
% Use Euclid's Algorithm to find the greatest 
% common divisor of two integers.
\def\gcd#1#2{{% #1 = a, #2 = b
    \ifnum#2=0 \edef\next{#1}\else
        \@tempcnta=#1 \@tempcntb=#2 \divide\@tempcnta by\@tempcntb
        \multiply\@tempcnta by\@tempcntb  % q*b
        \@tempcntb=#1
        \advance\@tempcntb by-\@tempcnta % remainder in \@tempcntb
        \ifnum\@tempcntb=0
            \@tempcnta=#2
            \ifnum\@tempcnta < 0 \@tempcnta=-\@tempcnta\fi
            \xdef\gcd@next{\noexpand%
                \def\noexpand\thegcd{\the\@tempcnta}}%
        \else
            \xdef\gcd@next{\noexpand\gcd{#2}{\the\@tempcntb}}%
        \fi
    \fi}\gcd@next
}
\newcommand\reduceFrac[2]
{%
   \gcd{#1}{#2}{\@tempcnta=#1 \divide\@tempcnta by\thegcd
   \@tempcntb=#2 \divide\@tempcntb by\thegcd
   \ifnum\@tempcntb<0\relax
      \@tempcntb=-\@tempcntb
        \@tempcnta=-\@tempcnta
    \fi
    \xdef\rfNumer{\the\@tempcnta}
    \xdef\rfDenom{\the\@tempcntb}}%
}

\reduceFrac{27}{81}
$\frac{\rfNumer}{\rfDenom}$
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Yiannis `gcd` is now in pgf 2.1 CVS and reduceFrac is called `\tkzReducFrac`in `tkz-tools-arith.tex`. Now it's a part of TL2011. `gcd`is also in `tkz-tools-arith.tex` but I made  a test to use pgfmath if the version is the CVS one . See my answer

Comment: @Altermundus that is great, I can now delete all these from my hardisk!

Comment: @ Yiannis Yes great but I'm afraid ... I hope there are not too many errors in all the packages

Comment: @Altermundus See if you can also make use of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12481/how-to-break-out-of-a-loop

Comment: @Yiannis I don't see this question. It's interesting

Answer (score 9):

Funny problem and it's a possibility to test TL 2011 with my package `tkz-fct`. This package calls `tkz-tool-arith.tex` and inside this file I define `gcd` and `\tkzReducFrac`. `gcd` now is a part of pgf CVS  with `isprime` `isodd` and `iseven`.
I use the code of Jake for random. The study of the function is not completed, I give this solution only to see what we can make with little tools.
I compile with xelatex and with -shell-escape because `tkz-fct` uses only `gnuplot`
`tkzReducFrac` defines two macros `\tkzMathFirstResult`and `\tkzMathSecondResult`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\begin{document}
\section{Problem}

\pgfmathsetseed{1}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\coeffa{random(2,10)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\coeffb{random(2,10)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\coeffc{random(2,10)}

Let \(x_1\) and \(x_2\) be the roots of \(\coeffa x^2 +\coeffb x +\coeffc=0\). Find  \(x_1x_2\).

\tkzReducFrac{\coeffc}{\coeffa}
\section{Solution}
\[
x_1x_2=\frac{\tkzMathFirstResult}{\tkzMathSecondResult}
\]

% only to make some tests
\pgfmathsetmacro\discrimin{\coeffb*\coeffb-4*\coeffa*\coeffc}   
\pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(notless(\discrimin,0)==1,">=0","<0")} 

$\Delta=b^2-4ac=\discrimin\pgfmathresult$  

$a=\coeffa$

\pgfmathsetmacro\xmid{-\coeffb/(2*\coeffa)}     
\pgfmathsetmacro\xmin{\xmid-5} % to adjust the grid and the background
\pgfmathsetmacro\xmax{\xmid+5} 

$-b/(2a)=\xmid$

% minimum to adjust vertically but it's possible to use a better code
\ifnum\coeffa > 0 
     \pgfmathsetmacro\ymin{-1-\discrimin/(\coeffa*\coeffa)}
     \pgfmathsetmacro\ymax{\ymin+10}
 \else 
   \pgfmathsetmacro\ymax{-1-\discrimin/(\coeffa*\coeffa)}
   \pgfmathsetmacro\ymin{\ymax-10}    
\fi


\begin{tikzpicture}
      \tkzInit[xmin=\xmin,xmax=\xmax,ymin=\ymin,ymax=\ymax]  
               \tkzGrid
               \tkzAxeXY 
\tkzFct[blue,thick]{\coeffa*x*x+\coeffb*x+\coeffc}
\end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @xport: +1 is for good answers, not for simply answering.

Comment: @xport: this was a good answer, but your comment here and elsewhere of "+1 for answering" implies differently.

Answer (score 9):

A solution with Lua that handles coefficients that are smaller than 2 correctly.

```
% Compile with lualatex.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
function gcd (a,b) 
    if b == 0 then
        return a
    end
    return gcd(b, a % b)
end

function makeproblem ()
    local a,b,c
    a = math.random (-10,10)
    if a == 0 then a = 1 end
    b = math.random (-10,10)
    c = math.random (-10,10)

    -- Pretty-print the equation.
    if a == - 1 then
        tex.sprint('-')
    elseif a ~= 1 then
        tex.sprint(a)
    end
    tex.sprint( 'x^2' )
    if b ~= 0 then
        if b > 0 then tex.sprint('+') end
        if b ~= 1 and b ~= -1 then tex.sprint(b) end
        if b == -1 then tex.sprint('-') end
        tex.sprint('x')
    end
    if c ~= 0 then
        if c > 0 then tex.sprint('+') end
        tex.sprint(c)
    end
    tex.sprint('=0')

    -- Simplify the solution
    local d
    d = gcd(a,c)
    a = a/d
    c = c/d

    local sign = 1
    if a < 0 then 
        sign = -1
        a    = -a
    end
    if c < 0 then
        sign = -sign
        c    = -c
    end

    -- Store the solution in \solution.
    tex.sprint('\\gdef\\solution{')
    if sign < 0 then tex.sprint('-') end
    if a == 1 or c == 0 then
        tex.sprint(c)
    else
        tex.sprint('\\frac{' .. c  ..'}{'.. a ..'}')
    end
    tex.sprint('}')
end
```

```latex
\end{luacode*}
\newcommand\makeproblem{\directlua{makeproblem()}}

\begin{document}

\section{Problem}
Let \(x_1\) and \(x_2\) be the roots of \(\makeproblem\). Find  \(x_1x_2\).

\section{Solution}
\[
x_1x_2=\solution
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: +1 It is also good. However, it will become more complicated for creating more complicated math problems.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a bit of meta code to pretty-print the Lua code chunk. Feel free to revert.

Answer (score 6):

MATLAB version, possibly adaptable to Octave:

First, download my [parsetex.m](http://www.cae.tntech.edu/~mwr/parsetex.m) function to somewhere in your search path. Next,
make a template .tex file named foo-gradingkey.tex, with contents like

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Hello, **studentName**.

\section{Problem}
% ^^a=round(9*rand)+1;^^
% ^^b=round(10*rand);^^
% ^^c=round(10*rand);^^
Let \(x_1\) and \(x_2\) be the roots of \(**a** x^2 + **b** x + **c**=0\).
Find  \(x_1x_2\). 

\section{Solution}
\[ x_1x_2=\frac{**c**}{**a**}= **c/a** \] 
\end{document}
```

Paired double carets and paired double asterisks indicate MATLAB code to be evaluated. Material in paired double carets will remain in the final file, while material in pared double asterisks will be replaced with the evaluated result.

Run the following command in MATLAB:

```
parsetex('foo-%s.tex',{'Mike Renfro'},{'renfro'});
```

which results in the following message on the command line:

```
Creating file foo-renfro.tex: done
```

The contents of foo-renfro.tex will be something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Hello, Mike Renfro.

\section{Problem}
% ^^a=round(9*rand)+1;^^
% ^^b=round(10*rand);^^
% ^^c=round(10*rand);^^
Let \(x_1\) and \(x_2\) be the roots of \(10 x^2 + 2 x + 10=0\).
Find  \(x_1x_2\). 

\section{Solution}
\[ x_1x_2=\frac{10}{10}= 1 \] 
\end{document}
```

It's not perfect, since I've not yet managed to get it to reduce fractions to simplest form, i.e., 2/5 ends up being evaluated as 0.4.

Comment: +1: it is interesting. Unfortunately, Matlab & Mathematica are very expensive softwares.

Comment: This approach is very fluid coding workflow.

Comment: @xport: it should work in [GNU Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) ([this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Cell-Arrays.html) looks like they have compatible cell arrays), but I've not tried it myself.

Comment: I haven't looked through this solution thoroughly to see if this would solve your problem with expressing decimal numbers as rational fractions, but Matlab has a `rat` function that might help here; however, it also might make for messy fractions when the answer is better-expressed as an approximate decimal number.

Answer (score 1):

Even more late to the party, but I cannot left this questions without a R/knitr approach. The MWE is in Rmarkdown but it produce a true LaTeX document compiled with pdflatex (it is on-topic).

This produce random coefficients (i a reduced range), reduce `a` and `c` when needed to obtain the smallest fraction, show the solution and if the plot will produce 0, 1 or 2 roots (intercepts) and make the plot showing that.

The MWE, as is, produce a different output in each compilation. If you want to reproduce just the images posted, uncomment `set.seed(12111)` or `set.seed(1931)` or the some similar commands that produce others possible outputs).

I left as procrastination exercises if every possible combination of coefficients work well without and search the right seed number to produce only one root (obviously, without fixing manually the coefficients).

> [image: MWE]

---

> [image: mwe2]

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: default
---

## Random coefficients

```{r abc, echo=F}

# Some Reproducicle random results: 
# set.seed(1235)                    # 2 roots,   
# set.seed(1211)                    # 2 roots, inverted U
# set.seed(931)                     # 2 root, automatically reduced coef.    
# set.seed(1931)                    # No roots 
# set.seed(726)                     # No roots, inverted U
# ???????                           # One root 

a <- 0
b <- 0
c <- 0

while (a==0){a=sample(-10:10, 1)} 
while (b==0){b=sample(-10:10, 1)} 
while (c==0|c==a){c=sample(-10:10, 1)} 

# paste(a,b,c)
# b^2-(4*a*c)
# if ((b^2-(4*a*c)) > 0) {cat("OK")} else {cat("chungo")}

library(MASS)
e <- c/a
f <- attr(fractions(c/a),"fracs")

a1 <- a
c1 <- c

getfracs <- function(frac) {
  tmp <- strsplit(attr(frac,"fracs"), "/")[[1]]
  list(numerator=as.numeric(tmp[1]),denominator=as.numeric(tmp[2]))}

fracs <- getfracs(fractions(c/a))

num <- fracs$numerator
den <- fracs$denominator
if(is.na(den)){a=a1;c=c1}else{a=den;c=num}

```




a = `r a`  (`r a1`/`r a1/a`), b = `r b`, c = `r c` (`r c1`/`r c1/c`)    

## Problem

Let \(x_1\) and \(x_2\) be the roots of \(`r a` x^2 +`r b`x +`r c`=0\). Find  \(x_1x_2\).

## Solution 

\[
x_1x_2=\frac{`r c`}{`r a`}= `r c/a`
\]

Since  \(b^2-4ac=`r b^2-(4*a*c)`\)
```{r, echo=T,results='asis',echo=F}

x <- (b^2)-(4 * a * c)

if (x < 0) {cat(" (<0), there are no intercept.\n")} else 
      {if (x == 0) {cat(", there are one intercept.\n")} 
      else {cat("(>0), there are two intercepts.\n")}}
```


``` {r, echo=F }
# , dev="tikz"
x <- seq(-5,5,.1)
y  <- (a*(x^2))+ (b*x) + c 
plot(y~x, type="l",lwd=2,col="blue", bty="n",ylim=c(min(y)-10,max(y))) # 
abline(v=0, lty=2, col="green") 
abline(h=0, lty=2, col="red") 

```
````