# Consistant formatting with siunitx and pgf: Thousands Separator

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, siunitx

I like the default behavior of [the `siunitx` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx) in that the thousands separator is *not* applied to four digit numbers, but *is* applied when the number of digits exceeds four.  In documents that contain `pgfplots`, `\pgfmathprintnumber` is used for the formatting of the numbers, but it does not exhibit this behavior:

[image]

Is there a setting for `\pgfmathprintnumber` to format numbers similar to the `\num` macro from the `siunitx` package so either method can be freely used with for formatting numbers

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgf}

\sisetup{
    group-digits=true,
    group-separator={\,},
}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd, set thousands separator={\,}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rll}
siunitx: &\num{9000}                &\num{19000} \\
    pgf: &\pgfmathprintnumber{9000} &\pgfmathprintnumber{19000} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## `siunitx`-independent PGF solution

The same behaviour of `siunitx`’ option `group-four-digits` set to false can be achieved in PGF with the `/pgf/number format/min exponent for 1000 sep` style.

From the [PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), section 66.1 “Changing display styles”, p. 547:

> `/pgf/number format/min exponent for 1000 sep={<number>}` (no default, initially `0`)
>
> Defines the smallest exponent in scientic notation which is required to draw thousand separators. The exponent is the number of digits minus one, so `<number>` = 4 will use thousand separators starting with 1e4 = 10000.
>
> A value of `0` disables this feature (negative values are ignored).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgf}

\sisetup{
    group-digits=true,
    group-separator={\,},
}

\pgfkeys{
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
        set thousands separator={\,},
        min exponent for 1000 sep=4,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rll}
siunitx: &\num{9000}                &\num{19000} \\
    pgf: &\pgfmathprintnumber{9000} &\pgfmathprintnumber{19000} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output of min exponent for 1000 sep = 4]

## `siunitx` and PGF

If you want to use `siunitx` and PGF’s number printing system *consistently*  together you should check out `siunitx` “little” `\SendSettingsToPgf` macro.

From the [`siunitx` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/siunitx/siunitx.pdf), section 7.9 “Transferring settings to PGF”, p. 63:

> The numerical engine in the `pgf` package has settings similar to those in `siunitx`. To
>   enable working with both packages easily, the macro `\SendSettingsToPgf` is available.
>   It will set some commonly-used numerical formatting options in `pgf` to the current
>   values used by `siunitx` to make using the two packages together more convenient for
>   end users. This function can be used at any point after loading both the `pgf` and `siunitx`
>   packages.

As `group-four-digits` is set to `false` per default there are no further adjustment needed in your example.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgf}

\sisetup{
    group-digits=true,
    group-separator={\,},
%   group-four-digits=false,% default setting
}
\SendSettingsToPgf

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rll}
siunitx: &\num{9000}                &\num{19000} \\
    pgf: &\pgfmathprintnumber{9000} &\pgfmathprintnumber{19000} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output of \SendSettingsToPgf]

Comment: I saw that but thought it only applied for scientific notation... Thanks.

Comment: You might wan to use `\SendSettingsToPgf` to send the `siunitx` settings to `pgf`, as this deals with the various possibilities automatically without having to have the settings twice explicitly.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, the second method doesn't work for me. pgf seems to ignore siunitx settings. I have siunitx v2.5m and pgf v2.10.

Comment: @Luigi I have used `v2.5f` in my answer. Though, I experience some inconsistency with `v2.5m` too. It seems, that not all settings are forwarded correctly, yes.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Please log issue: https://bitbucket.org/josephwright/siunitx/issues/ and I'll take a look.

Comment: @Luigi I can confirm that `\SendSettingsToPgf` works again in [`v2.5n`](https://bitbucket.org/josephwright/siunitx/commits/bf7191b994c2).