# \chapterprecistoc command causes infinite compile time when custom decimal to fraction conversion command is used

Tags: macros, memoir

Please see this MWE.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

% Adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176815/14103
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\newcommand{\dectofrac}[1]{\begingroup%
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/frac}% Format as fraction
  \let\frac\sfrac% Let \frac act like \sfrac
  \pgfmathprintnumber{#1}\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\chapterprecishere{\dectofrac{0.25}}
\chapterprecistoc{\dectofrac{0.25}} % Works fine when this line is
                                    % commented out or the \dectofrac
                                    % is not used

\end{document}
```

Compilation causes the process to run indefinitely without any error message.
We can exit only using Ctrl-C
which shows the following as terminal output:

> ```
> Interruption.
> \pgfkeys@parse ...uturelet \pgfkeys@possiblerelax 
>                                                   \pgfkeys@parse@main 
> l.16 \chapterprecistoc{\dectofrac{0.25}}
> ```

When the line containing `\chapterprecistoc` is commented out
compilation proceeds without the slightest error.  The culprit here is
the `\dectofrac` command since the `\chapterprecistoc` will work fine
if we don't use this command.
I am otherwise clueless here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare a robust command `\inlinedectofrac`, which can be used inside of `\chapterprecistoc`.
Or you can use `\protect` before `\dectofrac`.

For more Information see [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands)

```
\documentclass{memoir}

% Adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176815/14103
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\newcommand{\dectofrac}[1]{\begingroup%
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/frac}% Format as fraction
  \let\frac\sfrac% Let \frac act like \sfrac
  \pgfmathprintnumber{#1}\endgroup}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\inlinedectofrac}[1]{%
  \dectofrac{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\chapterprecistoc{\inlinedectofrac{0.25}}

\chapter{Second}
\chapterprecistoc{\protect\dectofrac{0.75}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `\NewDocumentCommand`, which is available as `xfrac` loads `xparse`; this doesn't need `\protect` or another command.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

% Adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176815/14103
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\NewDocumentCommand{\dectofrac}{m}{\begingroup%
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/frac}% Format as fraction
  \let\frac\sfrac% Let \frac act like \sfrac
  \pgfmathprintnumber{#1}\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\chapterprecistoc{\dectofrac{0.25}}

\chapter{Second}
\chapterprecistoc{\dectofrac{0.75}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\NewDocumentCommand{\dectofrac}{m}{<same code>}` would be sufficient: it doesn't require `\protect` or another command. It is available because `xfrac` loads `xparse`.

Comment: Not really like you did: `<same code>` referred to the original code in the definition of `\dectofrac`. I added the correct code.