# Creating random problems by using rand option

Tags: programming, random-numbers

I would like to generate random questions based on a random integer input. I have tried he code from a site online and tweaked it so that it generates more than one random problem but evidently it does not generate random problems. In the enumerate, the same problem appears. Any insight into the matter will be highly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,enumitem}
\usepackage{lcg,calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\reinitrand[first=1, last=10, counter=num]  \rand
\reinitrand[first=2, last=20, counter=deno] \rand
\reinitrand[first=2, last=5, counter=coeff] \rand
\setcounter{num}{\value{coeff}*\value{num}} 
\setcounter{deno}{\value{coeff}*\value{deno}}
\newcommand{\fracquestion}[1]{%
\foreach \i in {1,...,#1}
{
\item $\dfrac{\thenum}{\thedeno}$
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\fracquestion{5}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you move the random number generating code within the `\foreach` and ajdust the seed values you get:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,enumitem}
\usepackage{lcg,calc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\fracquestion}[1]{%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{%
      \reinitrand[first=\i, last=10, counter=num]  \rand
      \reinitrand[first=\i, last=20, counter=deno] \rand
      \reinitrand[first=\i, last=5, counter=coeff] \rand
      \setcounter{num}{\value{coeff}*\value{num}} 
      \setcounter{deno}{\value{coeff}*\value{deno}}
      \item $\dfrac{\thenum}{\thedeno}$
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \fracquestion{5}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively you could just use the random number generation capability already built into PGF (which is included with `tikz`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\fracquestion}[1]{%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{%
      \item $\dfrac{\pgfmathparse{random(10)}\pgfmathresult}{\pgfmathparse{random(20)}\pgfmathresult}$%
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \fracquestion{5}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try to apply the same principle to simple quadratic equations to try to generate problems with equal roots, distinct roots and imaginary roots.

Comment: I am looking at [random math problems](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20404/10898). How can I get only the quadratic equations and using the same principle as above; that is, with random problems generated?

Comment: Huh??? Not sure exactly what you want to do. A quadratic equation just needs three random numbers `\a`, `\b`, `\c`, and then `$\a x^2 + \b x + \c$` would be a randomly generated quadratic equation. I suspect that you are looking for something else.. If it is not related to thrust of this question (i.e., how to generate random numbers) it should probably be posted as a new question.

Comment: @PeterGrillOk I will try to post as a new question.

Comment: Ok, you should include a link back to this question in case it is deemed a duplicate.

Comment: How do you compile 40 different tests? I'm running a bash script, but they all have the same 'random' numbers...

Comment: OK, figured. This line was missing from the preamble `\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}`.