# Including a Matlab table in document

Tags: tables, matlab

Using Matlab I got a table. Now I want to integrate in a LaTeX document. I assume it works like including an image in a document.

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
latex_table = latex(sym(A))

latex_table =

\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 2 & 3\\ 4 & 5 & 6\\ 7 & 8 & 9 \end{array}\right)


 \begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{...}
  ***...latex_table ...***
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Could you specify the code a bit more. Right now you have mixed matlab and LaTeX code in your example. It would be useful to see what you do in matlab and LaTeX separately.

Comment: what are these `latex` and `sym` commands? can they be found int Matlab?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the easiest way of doing this is to format the data in Matlab and use `fprintf` to save it to a file. You can then include that file in your Latex-document.

```matlab
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
latex_table = latex(sym(A));
file = fopen('/path/to/output.tex','w');
fprintf(file,'%s',latex_table);
fclose(file);
```

Or you can write a Matlab function which output the latex-code as a macro.

```matlab
function [ ] = savetable(varargin)
% SAVETABLE(handle, matrix, file)

handle = char(varargin{1});
latex_table = latex(sym(varargin{2}));

file = fopen(varargin{3}, 'a');
fprintf(file,'\\newcommand{\\%s}{\n\t',handle);
fprintf(file,'\t%s\n}',latex_table);
fclose(file);
```

**Example**
Use can use this to write several different equations in the same file as shown below.

```matlab
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
B = [10 11 12;13 14 15;16 17 18];
savetable('eqA',A,'equations.tex')
savetable('eqB',B,'equations.tex')
```

A Latex-document might look something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{equations}

\begin{document}
    Here we have a nice matrix:
    \[
        \eqA{}
    \]
    And here is another one:
    \[
        \eqB{}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanx. This is exactly what was my first thought. But, how can i in latex open many equations.tex files. Infact, I want a latex file with 129 such detailed tables at specified  positions.

Comment: I added an example to my answer. The 'a' flag in fopen tells Matlab to _"Create and open a new file or open an existing file for writing, appending to the end of the file."_, so you can run `savetable` 129 times and output it all in one file, which then will contain all your equations. The rest is just a matter of calling the macros at the right place in the Latex code.

Comment: @ Ahlqvist I copy paste your latex code but I cann't use your latex code because I am getting a lot of errors. What to do?

Comment: Can you post any of the error messages? The code works for me. Does the Matlab script work? My `equations.tex` looks like this:
`\newcommand{\eqA}{\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 2 & 3\\ 4 & 5 & 6\\ 7 & 8 & 9 \end{array}\right)}` (and more line which looks similar).
You need to have all equations (eqA, eqB, et al.) defined in that file or it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The following is how you would use it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \[
    \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 2 & 3\\ 4 & 5 & 6\\ 7 & 8 & 9 \end{array}\right)
  \]
  \caption{Here is my table.}
\end{table}

This is a table generated in Matlab:
\[
  \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 2 & 3\\ 4 & 5 & 6\\ 7 & 8 & 9 \end{array}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

Note that you're inserting math content in a `table` (which is perfectly fine), but not necessary, even though intuitively a "table" (or two-dimensional structure) should be put inside a `table` or `tabular` environment. The second option ("inline" display math) is preferred.

Comment: i don't want to do it with mouse. I wish to insert it (all tables in a specified place )automatically.

Comment: @user31177: I don't understand. You want to type something like `A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]; latex_table = latex(sym(A))` in Matlab and have it automatically wrap it in a `table` environment? That would be something that has to be done on the Matlab side of things... not from within LaTeX.

Comment: Is my answer at [How to create a random math problem in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20443/3345) closer to what you want? Granted, it was originally written for making sets of homework assignments, but at its core, it's a way to make MATLAB insert content into a LaTeX document.