# Automating the formatting of Matlab table outputs into a TeX document

Tags: matlab, excel, excel2latex

I am using Matlab [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K990.png) to create tables with my descriptive statistics. A typical table looks something like:

[image: [1]: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html]

I can write this table to a perfect excel file using the function [writetable](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html) as follows:

```
writetable(T,filename)
```

This produces an excel file with the raw output.

Ideally however, I would like this to be formatted (e.g. 2 decimals, bold headers, simple horizontal lines) such that I can directly export it to my TeX document.

I was therefore wondering whether there are any known packages or methods that can help me automate this procedure?

Comment: Might be useful (or it is just a similar question using different way of doing) : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87642/including-a-matlab-table-in-document?rq=1

Comment: You can use pgfplotstable to construct a table to construct a table from a CSV file, as you describe -- if you could post a small CSV file, it might help those inclined to answer :)