# Special cases when using old-style figures

Tags: typography, oldstylenums

When using old-style figures, what are the special cases of using lining figures (if any), apart from maths?

For instance, are reference marks one such instance?

```
Some 1998 text which references~[1]
```

where the `1998` would be in old-style, should the `[1]` be in lining-style? i.e.,

```
Some 1998 text which references~$[1]$
```

Same with equation number marks? How about percents?

```
In 1989, there was 25\%
```

or

```
In 1989, there was $25$\%
```

(side question, should there be a `\thinspace` or something between the percent-sign and the numbers?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Bringhurst](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0881792063), 3.2.1:

> Use titling [lining] figures with full caps, and text [oldstyle] figures in all other circumstances

Some may find that a bit dogmatic, but I think, at least, that it's a good starting-point.

Comment: In http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8204/palatino-fonts-and-the-number-713 I thought they did not look nice in Tables, but later changed my mind http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12150/protrusion-of-fractions-in-tabulars.